# JMockit - not able to mock a public final field of a class

Tags: java, jmockit

i'm not able to mock a public final field of a class.

I have a locked class with a public final field (a complex object).

When i run tests Jmockit is returning Null pointer exceptions.

That locked class has got no getter or setter for that field, we normally access it directly, but with @Mocked it seems that it's not able to auto mock that field, what i'm doing wrong?

This is an example of the situation i have:

//METHOD to test

```
public static void xxx(final ComplexObjectA objA, ComplexObjectB objB, ComplexObjectC objC){
  try{
   //some code here
   anotherMethod(objB.myObject);
  } catch (blabla){}
}
```

//Complex Object B

```
public class ComplexObjectB extends SomeClass{
 public final SubComplexObject myObject;
}
```

//TEST

```
public class MyTest{

    @Mocked
    ComplexObjectA objA;
    @Mocked
    ComplexObjectB objB;
    @Mocked
    ComplexObjectC objC;


    @Test
    public void checkSomeNull() throws SubjectException, IOException, SQLException {
        new Expectations(){{
            objB.myObject.getProperty("XYZ"); result = "1";
        }};
        MyClass.xxx(objA,objB,null);
    }
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Mocking APIs only mock *methods* (and constructors, in the case of JMockit), not fields. 2) Mock objects (or mocked instances) are instantiated with *no state*; again, this is standard in any mocking API.

Comment: @Rogério that's ok but it is possible to mock the myObject or my only solution is to ask to have a method to Obtain that value instead of access to it directly?

Comment: You can have a mocked `myObject` instance inside a *non-mocked* `objB`.